Как провести стресс-тест CPU на tinycore linux?
Есть машина х32 i686 GNU/Linux Tinycore, как на ней можно провести стресс-тест CPU? Пробовал поставить утилиту stress, но судя по http://repo.tinycorelinux.net/8.x/x86/tcz/ утилита уже неактуальна.

mprime Torture Test (32-битная версия есть на официальном сайте https://www.mersenne.org/download/)


Сколько ядер выдает по cat /proc/cpuinfo? Если там одно, то любой из этих способов подойдет. Вы можете так же открыть несколько консолей и запустить несколько таких процессов и любоваться на вывод команды top, atop, или htop :)

Не стоит сразу сдаваться, если stress нет в репозитории :) Его можно собрать из исходников, при чем в любой системе с такой же архитектурой и закинуть собранный бинарь (наверняка, утилита простая и ей больше ничего не требуется).

Если консоль не нужна и требуется замерить температуру пальцем, или внешним термометром, может так же поискать "bash fork bomb" :) Например:
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x

bomb() {
   bomb | bomb &
  };
bomb





Выдаёт 2 блока с proccessor 0 и 1, я так понимаю, что это 2 ядра?
Спасибо за наводку, пытаюсь собрать, но в моём случае системе урезанная и пакету много чего не хватает, но, наверное, это лучший для меня вариант. Спасибо!


з.ы. собрать все же получилось, но для сборки потребовались autoreconf и automake! Спасибо, это то что нужно!

Да, 0...1 -- это два ядра. На самом деле, любой из примеров в пункте 1 запущенный два раза на двух ядрах бы нагрузил. Или для уверенности можно и четыре раза запустить: ну вырос бы load average и время отклика, ни и окей, ведь нагружено же ;) Незачто ;)

p7zip встроенный стресс тест на сжатие неплохой
7z b 



Официальный 7-Zip работает существенно быстрее чем устаревший p7zip (впрочем, я не уверен, заведётся ли официальный 7-Zip на i686 Tinycore); 2) Всё ж он сильно зависит от памяти, вышеупомянутый мной mprime грузил у меня проц намного сильнее чем 7z (и выявлял те ошибки, которые 7z выявить не смог)

